# Importing Excel SpreadSheets Into Access: Unable to Append All Data to the Table

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

I am importing sheets into my Access table. I have some fields set as Number Fields. The particular column for the Excel sheet is formatted as a Number type.

I get the unable to append error.

If I change the data type for the field to Short Text, it imports.

How do I get the data into the table as a number data type.

**Data Type for Table**
[image]

**Excel Cell Format**
[image]

Comment: 50 records failed - how many were attempted - what is different about those 50? This is a common issue with import from spreadsheet. Excel doesn't really have data types. Import operation just reads value in cell and decides data type. Data type assumed by Access is based on first few rows after header. Formatting as number might help but there is no guarantee.

Comment: All 50 records failed out of 50. I really can't format the field as a number data type anymore because if a phone number is unknown, it is stored as unknown in the excel cell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the error message in one of the image you attached, it seems like you are using a primary key from a column in the excel sheet you are importing from.

During importation, choose the option to allow MS Access add primary key.

Second message from same image you attached points to data type issue, for this you can format the cells in excel to number before importing(i am giving this advise based on your comment that when you change it to shorttext it imports fine)

Comment: There are no primary keys. I used the TransferSpreadSheet method in VBA. Now I cant format it as a number anymore because some phone numbers are stored as unknown.